# Adding extra field to insert query

Tags: c#, wpf, dbcontext

I have an application which wasn't made by me. This application has a form which uses `MySQL` and `DbContext` to store data into my database. I'm trying to add one extra field, but the problem I'm facing is that even though the model generated with the form values contains my new value, `DbContext` is not generating this extra field into the `query`, so this extra value is not being saved.

This is the method which actually saves the data into the table:

```
public virtual int Insert(T source)
{
    using (var context = new EyebusEntities())
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(source);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return source.Id;
    }
}
```

Obs.:

- `source` has the value which needs to be saved.
- Monitoring the queries using MySQL's general log, I could confirm that the field is missing from the query.

How exactly does `DbContext` generates the queries? And how would I be able to accomplish my objective?

Entity:

```
public partial class Ocorrencia : IEntity
    {
        public Ocorrencia()
        {
            this.OcorrenciaVideos = new HashSet<OcorrenciaVideo>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdOcorrenciaTipo { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
        public string Operador { get; set; }
        public string Motorista { get; set; }
        public string Cobrador { get; set; }
        public string Terceiros { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
        public string EmailsEnviados { get; set; }
        public string TipoOcorrenciaOutro { get; set; }
        public string Onibus { get; set; }     //field which don't get saved

        public virtual ICollection<OcorrenciaVideo> OcorrenciaVideos { get; set; }
        public virtual OcorrenciaTipo Tipo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept of `context.Set<T>`. That represents a table, and I don't know what kind of value you're talking about. Post the entity code and point out what "field" or property isn't being saved.

Comment: I edited with the entity code.

Comment: Does anyone know of any good tutorials regarding this methodology?